# Horizontal Lines do not span the Table length

Tags: tables, rules

In this table the horizontal lines, due to the `\multicolumn` command, do not fill the whole table.

One solution is to put extra horizontal space, as in the line with comment.
Is there another way (less trial and error) to do that?
Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|cccccc}
\toprule
 & \ce{COCl2(g)} & \ce{<-->} & \ce{CO(g)} & + & \ce{Cl2(g)} \\ 
\midrule 
inizio & 1 &  &  &  & \\ [1mm]
equilibrio &  $1 - \alpha$ &  &  $\alpha$ &  & $\alpha$ \\ [1mm]
moli totali & \multicolumn{6}{l}{$1 - \alpha + \alpha + \alpha = 1 + \alpha$} \\ [1mm]
%moli totali & \multicolumn{6}{l}{$1 - \alpha + \alpha + \alpha = 1 + \alpha\hspace{56mm}$} \\ [1mm]
frazioni molari & $\dfrac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}$ & & $\dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}$ & & $\dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}$ \\ [3mm]
pressioni parziali & $\left( \dfrac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right)P$ & & $\left( \dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right) P$ & & $\left( \dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right) P$ \\ [1mm]
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmmm... there is a missing `&` in the line with `inizio`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only 6 columns, so remove one `c` from the column specification. Also, since all the columns 2-6 are in math mode, spare these `$`s by adding `>{$}c<{$}` in the column specification.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l*5{>{$}c<{$}}}
\toprule
& \ce{COCl2(g)} & \ce{<-->} & \ce{CO(g)} & + & \ce{Cl2(g)} \\ 
\midrule 
inizio & 1 &  &  &  & \\ [1mm]
equilibrio & 1 - \alpha &  &  \alpha &  & \alpha \\ [1mm]
moli totali & \multicolumn{5}{l}{$1-\alpha+\alpha+\alpha = 1+\alpha$} \\ [1mm]
frazioni molari & \dfrac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha} & & \dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} & & \dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha} \\ [3mm]
pressioni parziali & \left(\dfrac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right)P & & \left(\dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right) P & & \left(\dfrac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\right)P \\ [1mm]
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Yes... or a `c` more in the tabular. ;-)

Comment: A "c" more in the tabular from a previous reaction with two reagents!